# what can be the reasons a checkbox is unselectable?

Tags: html, ajax, client, mootools

1. No element is positioned above it
2. there is no disabled property

I do create this element on the server side and send it via Ajax to the client, which
just put it in the correct place via `$('id-of-elm').innerHTML=text_from_ajax;`
If I change it to radio it works.

I am stumped.

Comment: @Neil my dear friend, trust me, I use mootools and not JQuery, please do not change my tags.

Comment: It happens... when we got the privilage to retag ..in the begining we will be greedy toretag somewhere some ones . :)

Answer (score 0):

For the next generations:

a containing element, (this checkbox is inside it), has an onclick event which returns false.
This was tested on FireFox.

for @zod (a simplified html)

```
<li>
  <input type='checkbox' name='a' value='6' />
  <input type='radio' name='b' value='7' />
</li>
```

Now, there is an event attached to the `li` in the onload of page and it is in combination with mootools. If you use that code above as is, you won't be able to reproduce this bug.

Comment: pls post the html code also. more helpful fornext generation :)

Comment: ah, returning false on clicks is often the wrong thing to do and can make for some fun bug chasing. just do `event.preventDefault()` when you can.

Comment: @Dimitar Christoff - tnx, I am adopting this suggestion